# arangodb export subset of a graph

Tags: graph, export, arangodb

Given a start node (_id) I need to get all nodes and edges connected to this starting node (within a named graph) and then create a new database with this "subgraph". I wonder if there is a built-in, or fast, way to do this, I was searching in arangoexport but cannot find how to specify graph name and node _id to create the subset of the graph to export.
Thanks

Comment: There is no direct way to do so, but it's possible with a few manual steps or you could write a script for it. Do you look for a solution that works cross-platform? How much data does the subgraph have?

Comment: As long as I can do it in bash or python (or AQL) is fine. Subgraphs now are small (few hundreds of nodes per subgraph) but it is intended to grow, so should be able to handle quite a lot of data per subraph

Comment: I would write some AQL to pull the data and call it from a foxx micro service. That way you can from anywhere thru an http call. Note that since you are just pulling data, there is no real advantage to create named subgraphs. I would just write a direct traversal to the collections as that gives you more flexibility.  Here is the documentation for traversals through collection sets (same performance as a named graph) https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/AQL/Graphs/Traversals.html#working-with-collection-sets